# How to open SwiftUI preview side by side to the code?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I have created new app with swiftUI in xcode11. and not able to find Xcode preview like shown in wwdc19.[image]

[image]

Comment: This was one of the first questions about SwiftUI :)

Comment: True, I just found out that. I did not know the proper word CANVAS to search.

Comment: You are also in the diff mode which won't show the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview only works on MacOS 10.15 Beta

Comment: check my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455112/2329948

Comment: For people who wanted to move preview it to the right side... Change Layout (right corner of workspace second last option) to "Canvas on Right"