# How to make SwiftUI default to preview on the right side as portrait?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm on Catalina version 10.15, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460064/how-to-open-swiftui-preview-side-by-side-to-the-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435054/xcode-11-canvas-does-not-show-up) do not answer my question.

In the following image you will see the preview is underneath my code, I want it side by side.

[image]

(What I want) Such as in the following view:
[image]

Comment: I upvoted, but this seems like a very first world problem

Comment: Well, sometimes it works and I get to learn something, or sometimes I learn that someone has been misinterpreting something I've said. Either way, I get to improve, or my content improves.

Comment: Good point. Btw did you get to check out my answer on ["SwiftUI Text foreground color turns the background color"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66944305/14351818)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is simply to widen the Xcode Window and the preview will jump to be side by side.

Comment: If someone figures out a way to make the preview side by side without needing to widen the Xcode window, I would upvote that.