# Text foreground color turns the background color

Tags: swiftui

It seems that in order to change the font/text color it is recommended to use the foreground property.  When I set that color to black, it also changes the capsule color .   How can I just specify the text to change color?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CapsuleButtonFilled: View {

    // MARK: - PROPERTIES

    var backgroundColor: Color

    // MARK:

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("The Solid")
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding()
        })
        .background(
            Capsule(style: .circular)
                .background(backgroundColor)
        )
    }
}

struct CapsuleButtonFilled_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CapsuleButtonFilled(backgroundColor: .orange)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I set that color to black, it also changes the capsule color .

The default fill color of `Capsule` is black. For example, here's a plain `Capsule` with nothing applied to it.

```
struct CapsuleButtonFilled: View {
    var body: some View {
        Capsule(style: .circular)
    }
}
struct CapsuleButtonFilled_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CapsuleButtonFilled()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 100))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Capsule with black fill]

Let's say you set `Color.green` for the text color.

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text("The Solid")
    .foregroundColor(Color.green) /// green!
    .background(backgroundColor)
    .padding()
})
.background(
    Capsule(style: .circular)
    .background(backgroundColor)
)
```

This is the result:

[image: Orange background with black capsule on top, then a smaller Text with green font and orange background on top of that.]

The `.foregroundColor()` applied to the `Text` doesn't affect the capsule.

Anyway, I assume that this is the result you want?

[image: Orange filled capsule with black Text on top]

You are using the wrong modifier to apply color to the capsule. Use `.fill()` instead of `.background()`.

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text("The Solid")
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    .background(backgroundColor)
    .padding()
})
.background(
    Capsule(style: .circular)
    .fill(backgroundColor)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you used (.fill) to change the foreground color of a shape. You should use (.foregroundColor) if your app's minimum iOS support is under iOS 17. And if your app's minimum version support is iOS 17 or above you should use (.foregroundStyle). Modify the background color after declaring the frame if you want to change the full background of the particular section or view.

I hope this will help.

```
Button(action: { 
print("Do something...")
}, label: {
    Text("The Solid")
    .foregroundColor(.white) // This foreground color is for your text
    .background(backgroundColor) // your desired background color for the button
    .padding()
})
.background(
    Capsule(style: .circular)
    .background(backgroundColor) // your desired background color
) // This background is for the whole background of your view
```