# Xcode 11: How to enable/fix live Interacting preview option of Xcode (for attached live preview on apple device)?

Tags: ipad, xcode, preview, user-interface, swift

I am trying to get Interaction of my swiftUI interface live on my attached iPad Pro(Running iOS 13) but its not working. It can be seen in screenshot  that it is (gray scaled) disabled (in WWDC it was blue). Is this a bug or I am missing any step. 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cWnG.png)[[image: screenshot 1]] 
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435054/xcode-11-canvas-does-not-show-up/58337153#58337153