# Xcode 11 beta swift ui preview not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Just playing with Swift UI basic app and the preview canvas is not showing even though I'm in canvas mode. App runs, and I have this little snippet what am I missing?

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ensure that your Mac is running macOS 10.15 beta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Canvas for SwiftUI previews does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435054/xcode-canvas-for-swiftui-previews-does-not-show-up)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To preview and interact with views from the canvas in Xcode, ensure your Mac is running on **Catalina MacOS**.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views

Please check apple document in the following URL
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_2_release_notes

> Xcode 11 beta supports development with SwiftUI.
>
> Note
>
> Tools for SwiftUI development are only available when running on macOS
>   Catalina 10.15 beta.

Comment: I wonder why they are forcing you to upgrade an entire OS just to be able to use some newer version of an SDK.

Answer (score 363):

Maybe someone is looking for this:
`Editor -> Canvas (Alt + Command + Enter)`

Comment: 1 hour looking for this button. It makes me wonder who's the blessed developer who placed it there.

Answer (score 67):

To open the preview canvas, just go to `Editor -> Canvas`

Or do <kbd>Alt + Command + Enter</kbd>

If your macOS version is below 10.15, you will get the below error

[image]

Update mac and try the same.

Answer (score 25):

## From the editor:

Top-Right corner of the editor, and then:

[image]

---

## From the menu

`Editor -> Canvas`

[image]

---

## Shortcuts

#### Open Canvas

<kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>↩ return</kbd>

#### Refresh canvas

<kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

---

#### A note about the macOS 

In the mac environment, you can search for any menu option under the **Help** menu, then it will open the exact menu path you are looking for.

For example, searching for **can**vas result in this:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Additionally, if you are using macOS system older than beta version like 10.14 you can use Xcode playground to preview with following code.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView : View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
 PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Comment: it gives this error - No such module 'PlaygroundSupport'

Comment: Is it possible that you have created Playground for macOS or something else? Can you try to create new Playground @ElshadKarimov

Comment: Catalina + Xcode 11b3 + Playground = Not working Preview

Comment: If you are using Catalina why you are trying to use Playground? My answer is people who is not using macOS 10.15 Catalina. @iTux

Comment: @AtalayAşa because I would not create app for iPhone or Mac, I was try SwiftUI :) After all tries I did create app for iOS with SwiftUI, and now is all good :)

Answer (score 15):

I'm running Xcode 12.2 on Catalina 10.15.7, and I not only need to make sure Canvas is selected but then I need to select Create Preview from the Editor menu.

[image: Xcode Editor menu]

Comment: Turns out this is necessary if you create a Swift file, but not if you create a SwiftUI file. I think a SwiftUI file is just a Swift file plus it creates the preview for you.

Answer (score 10):

To preview and interact with views from the canvas in Xcode, ensure your Mac is running macOS 10.15 beta.

Answer (score 2):

**Alt + Command + Enter**

Will solve the issue

Comment: Command + Option + Return for Mac users :)

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode 11 Beta 6**, there is a known issue and workaround for views that do not have their certain flags set (see below).

If this applies to you, and you are unable to set the corresponding flags, you may need to remove the `#if debug` flag around `ContentView_Previews` until the issue is fixed in a future Xcode release.

See the [Xcode 11 Beta 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_6_release_notes):

> Preview providers that are defined in projects which don’t have `-DDEBUG` set for `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` and wrapped in `#if DEBUG` don’t display in the canvas. That happens, for example, in Objective-C apps which that never had occasion to specify `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS`. (51138834)
>
> **Workaround:** Remove the `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` from around the `PreviewProvider` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this xcode_11_beta_5_release_notes** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_5_release_notes .

> With Xcode 11 beta 5, previews are only available on macOS Catalina
>   10.15 beta 5, and only Xcode 11 beta 5 supports previews on macOS Catalina 10.15 beta 5. (52059562)

Answer (score -1):

I have restarted the Xcode and machine and it's worked for me.
You can try this for many problems.