# Xcode 12 SwiftUI cannot find Automatic Preview

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, preview

I am working on an app in SwiftUI in Xcode 12.2.

I have accidentally deleted the Automatic Preview Tab. I cannot seem to find the option to bring it back. Here is a screenshot of my Xcode:

[image: My XCode without the automatic preview]

Where do I enable the Automatic preview and bring it back so I can see real-time updates of my UI?

Comment: Hi Christian, Any Xcode related question(s) I recommend you google first (I’m sure you will find something). Anyway check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64400725/14073532).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11 beta swift ui preview not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678354/xcode-11-beta-swift-ui-preview-not-showing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Canvas for SwiftUI previews does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435054/xcode-canvas-for-swiftui-previews-does-not-show-up)

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to find it is from the menu "Editor > Canvas"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In your Xcode snapshot, there is a button the top right corner with a bunch of horizontal lines. Click it and then click Canvas and the preview should come back. FYI, the preview canvas is different than a Storyboard, which is what you included in the "What I want" image.